# Resolving dependencies in OWIN WEB API Startup.cs with ninject

Tags: .net, ninject, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2 App, with two classes that both depend on another class, and i'm using ninject to resolve the dependancies.

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private IUserService _userService;


    public AuthorizationServerProvider(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

}

public class RefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public RefreshTokenProvider(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
```

In the startup.cs class i need to use the above two classes, but of course i cannot use constructor injection in the startup class, as that is initialised before Ninject is.

What's a way around this so that the references to _tokenProvider and 
_authServerProvider in the ConfigureAuth method?

```
public class Startup
{
    private AuthorizationServerProvider _authServerProvider;        
    private RefreshTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true, //TODO: HTTPS
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = _authServerProvider, 
            RefreshTokenProvider = _tokenProvider
        };

}
```

Here's the CreateKernel Method

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();


            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And here's where I register my services

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {

        kernel.Bind<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>().ToSelf();
        kernel.Bind<SimpleRefreshTokenProvider>().ToSelf();

}
```

I've followed the advice in the ninject [docs](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-a-OWIN-WebApi-application), but to no avail.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way.  Well, partially the wrong way anyways.  You can't get OWIN to inject dependencies into the Startup class.  So, you'll have to use the kernel that gets configured with `app.UseNinjectMiddleware()` to resolve your options configuration class.  We'll do this with a Lazy kernel.

First, you should be configuring this in Startup.Auth.cs.  Also, you've got some redundancy in there.. `app.UseNinjectWebApi(config)` will call `app.UseWebApi(config)` (see [the source](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost/OwinWebApiAppBuilderExtensions.cs)).  I also don't know why you're calling `WebApiConfig.Register()` there because that's typically called in Global.asax.cs

In any event, it should look like this (I haven't tested this, but it should be close):

First, we're going to move your kernel creation to a lazy method, and then have your `UseNinjectMiddleware()` call in `Startup.Configuration()` method use the lazy kerel in the Startup class as a member.  This works best I think as a simple lambda delegate, rather than creating a static CreateKernel method.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private readonly Lazy<IKernel> _kernel = new Lazy<IKernel>(() =>
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // here for brevity, move this to a RegisterServices or similar method,
        // 
        kernel.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>()
            .To<MyOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>();
        kernel.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
            .To<AuthorizationServerProvider>();
        kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>().To<RefreshTokenProvider>();
        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<MyUserService>();
        return kernel;
    });

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => _kernel.Value);
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Then in your ConfigureAuth()

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   // .... other auth code

   // Yes, boo hiss, service location, not much choice...
   // Setup Authorization Server
   app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(_kernel.Value
       .Get<MyOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>().GetOptions());
}
```

Then create an interface:

```
public interface IOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions 
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions GetOptions();
};
```

Create your implementation:

```
public class MyOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions : IOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions 
{
     private IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider _provider;
     private IAuthenticationTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

     public MyOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions(IAuthenticationTokenProvider tProvider,
         IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider provider)
     {
         _provider = provider;
         _tokenProvider = tProvider;
     }
     public OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions GetOptions()
     {
         return new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
                    {
                       AllowInsecureHttp = true, //TODO: HTTPS
                       TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                       AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                       Provider = _provider, 
                       RefreshTokenProvider = _tokenProvider
                    };
     }
}
```

**EDIT (4/6/15):**

Upon further thought on this, I think the `Lazy<T>` adds an addition reference that is really unnecessary. This can be modified to achieve the same results in a much cleaner way as such:

Create a new Startup.Ninject.cs class, and put it in App_Start:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public IKernel ConfigureNinject(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var kernel = CreateKernel();
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel)
           .UseNinjectWebApi(config);

        return kernel;
    }

    public IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        return kernel;
    }
}

public class NinjectConfig : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        RegisterServices();
    }

    private void RegisterServices()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>()
            .To<MyOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>();
        kernel.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
            .To<AuthorizationServerProvider>();
        kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>().To<RefreshTokenProvider>();
        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<MyUserService>();
    }
}
```

Then, in Startup do this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var kernel = ConfigureNinject(app);
        ConfigureAuth(app, kernel);
    }
}
```

Finally, Modify ConfigureAuth to take the second parameter and use that instead.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, IKernel kernel)
{
   // .... other auth code

   // Yes, boo hiss, service location, not much choice...
   // Setup Authorization Server
   app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(
       kernel.Get<MyOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>().GetOptions());
}
```

Comment: I'm using Autofac and this provided a guide which works

Comment: @ObiOnuorah could you share your solution, I am running into the same issue integrating OWIN with my MVC5 webapp using Autofac. Thanks!