# Ninject can not create a controller error in WebApi 2

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use Ninject as my DI Container in my WebApi.

I used the following code which I found from the same question in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351034/resolving-dependencies-in-owin-web-api-startup-cs-with-ninject) but again it gives me the same error

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'SendOrderToInspectorController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public
>
> InnerException:Type
>   'SampleAspNetWebApi.Controllers.SendOrderToInspectorController' does
>   not have a default constructor

```
namespace SampleAspNetWebApi
    {
        public class Startup
        {

            private readonly Lazy<IKernel> _kernel = new Lazy<IKernel>(() =>
            {
                var kernel = new StandardKernel();

                kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                // here for brevity, move this to a RegisterServices or similar method,
                // 
                kernel.Bind<ISaveOrderForInspector>().To<SaveOrderForInspector>();
                return kernel;
            });


public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {  

                app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => _kernel.Value);
                JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
                        RequiredScopes = new[] { "write", "read" }
                    });

                app.UseResourceAuthorization(new AuthorizationManager());
                app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register());
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my controller:

```
   public class SendOrderToInspectorController : ApiController
    {
        public ISaveOrderForInspector SaveOrderForInspector { get; set; }


        public SendOrderToInspectorController(ISaveOrderForInspector saveOrderForInspector)
        {
            SaveOrderForInspector = saveOrderForInspector;
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This is my SaveOrderForInspector class as well:

```
public class SaveOrderForInspector : ISaveOrderForInspector
    {
        public InspectorOrder InspectorOrder
        {
            get { return _inspectorOrder; }
            set { _inspectorOrder = value; }
        }

        public Inspector Inspector
        {
            get { return _inspector; }
            set { _inspector = value; }
        }

        private readonly FairShareContext _ctx = new FairShareContext();
        private InspectorOrder _inspectorOrder=new InspectorOrder();
        private Inspector _inspector=new Inspector();

        public SaveOrderForInspector()
        {

        }}
```

Comment: Would you show your implementation for the `SaveOrderForInspector` class please? Signature and constructor(s) only.

Comment: Weird. Looks pretty much correct to me. Two things: I assume you don't have some other interfaces or classes laying around such as another `ISaveOrderForInspector` and all namespaces are named properly such as class `SendOrderToInspectorController` belongs to the `Controllers` namespace. Also, just for the sake of understanding what's happening: if you added a default constructor to your `SendOrderToInspectorController` class, does the DI container still complain?

Comment: it doesn't complain but the problem is the SaveOrderForInspector will be null.

Comment: Makes sense. Sounds like the DI container can't find any constructor for which it can resolve all dependencies hence it tries to find the default constructor. In other words: either the statement `kernel.Bind<ISaveOrderForInspector>().To<SaveOrderForInspector>()` is not considered (e. g. overwritten or anything) or the kernel you expect to be used is not. Can you debug from where you trigger the creation of `SendOrderToInspectorController` and check the correctly initialised DI container is begin used?