# The name 'ConfigureNinject' does not exist in the current context

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, owin, ninject

I want to inject a data service in owin startup file. For that i'm using ninject DI.

Searching in stack overflow i got the link here [Resolving dependencies in OWIN WEB API Startup.cs with ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351034/resolving-dependencies-in-owin-web-api-startup-cs-with-ninject?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) where the solution given by mr Erik Funkenbusch.
 Over the link i followed the part EDIT (4/6/15). Do so i'm getting the error at startup file "var kernel = ConfigureNinject(app);"

> The name 'ConfigureNinject' does not exist in the current context.

As instructed i have followed by creating the class named Startup.Ninject.cs under App_start folder.

Would be great to help me out of this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both your Startup.Ninject.cs and Startup.cs files have the class defined as:

```
public partial class Startup
```

Note that you have to add `partial` to your existing Startup class.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry busy with work.  Yes, its inside partial class. Meanwhile i have the googled tried this blog. [Befriending ASP.NET Web.API2, OWIN and Ninject](http://www.alexzaitzev.pro/2014/11/webapi2-owin-and-ninject.html)

Its easy to do follow up. Thanks for help.